# How to dynamically create dictionaries of lists in python using a variables string data

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am looping through a CSV file and want to group all common rows based on a given column into a dictionary populated with the rest of that rows values.

example:

```
Date, Name, Gender, Address 

01/02/2019, John Doe, Male, 1 example street

21/12/2018, Mary Robinson, Female, 2 Lane St.

05/06/2017, John Doe, Male, 1 example street

dates = []
names = []
genders = []
addresses = []

for row in readFile: 
    date = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    gender = row[2]
    address = row[3]

    names.append(name)
    dates.append(dates)
    genders.append(gender)
    addresses.append(address)




    if name not in names:
       #Create Dictionary with using the value of name. (exec?)
       #Then populate dictionary with rest of row.
```

So I should end up with two dictionaries. One called John Doe and one called
Mary Robinson.

eg:

```
MaryRobinson = {
  "date": "21/12/2018",
  "name": "Mary Robinson",
  "gender": "Female",
   "Address": "2 Lane St."
}
```

Perhaps I would be better of using a list as I want to keep the option of storing more than one address.

I do not understand how to dynamically create a list from a variable value.
I have read it's bad practice.

Note: College assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `exec` if you wanted to but I don't think that would be really useful in your case (then you'd have to evaluate the name strings again every time you want to access them). I'd suggest you get one "master" dictionary where you have the names as keys, and the dictionaries as values. It would be something along the lines of (have not actually ran it):

```
data = {}
names = []

for row in readFile:

    date = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    gender = row[2]
    address = row[3]

    names.append(name)

   if name not in names:
       data[name] = {"date":date, "gender":gender, "address":address}
```